# What is a good way to learn clean topology?

Tags: topology

I started using Blender 1 year ago, and now when I want to try and make a model of a car I see where my problem is.
Model looks very ugly because my topology for something like that is horrible haha. Now, I want to learn some rules for connecting vertexes, for faces and all about polygonal modeling rules.
Can you recommended me some books or sites or PDF books, or something like that? **Because I really want learn topology**

[image: You can see problem here]

Comment: Hi, Marko Kovačević, I hope you do not mind my edit. I tried to correct some mistakes so you do not need to be sorry for bad Engish ;). I hope I did not change the meaning of what you wanted to communicate in any way. Please forgive me and edit the question again in case you don't like any part of the edit. Hope this helps you get more answers.

Comment: Thank you, for your spend time to correct me, that is helpful :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender and http://topologyguides.com/

Answer (score 3):

## A good way to learn to use clean topology is to do a lot of modelling

'Clean' topology is topology that is easy and convenient to work with. We avoid triangles because they do not allow the use of a lot of functions related to edge loops or do not look nice after surface subdivision, we avoid non-manifold geometry because some algorithms are confused by it and do not work as expected, we use as little of geometry as possible to define shapes and forms because it is easier to work with and there is less lag, we use denser geometry where objects are going to deform because they do not look nice when deformed otherwise and so on and so on. Clean topology has natural reasons to be - that's why you learn it naturally while modelling. If you model something for animations, you need to take extra care to understand the rigging and animation process enough to have suitable topology, but else than that, most of the time the more modelling you do, the better you get at judging what topology is 'clean'.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing some exercises.. small disposable puzzles that aren't overwhelming, and are quite fun (if you enjoy that kind of thing :) ). A search on 'subd modelling exercises' turns up quite a few. Which ones you choose will be a matter of taste. You can kick off with some Blender-specific ones to get some shortcuts under your belt. After that, it doesn't matter which software the exercises are in.

Most topology problems fall into well-known patterns; there aren't too many to become familiar with.

Comment: Very good advice. Small disposable modelling exercises that are not overwhelming is a very good way to learn in general. I have seen people trying to learn modelling with difficult objects like cars, human body, superheros... I think these should be simple objects instead that the learning person could have and hold in their hands while modeling or photograph themselves: a lighter, a srew, a spoon, a pen, a pencil sharpener, a key, glasses, an electric plug, a toaster, a banana, wifi router... - all perfectly good exercises for learning.